# unable to flash ROM in HUAWEI phone

Tags: rom-flashing, huawei

I have a H30-U10 Huawei phone that is not turning on. when I press the <kbd>power</kbd> button, it freezes on the logo screen and stuck at there. The current ROM on the device is `H30-U10 V100R001C900B127`. Also, I tried to flash same ROM and higher versions. But, I get following error:

```
dloading module MBR.....
dload:update partition MBR failed
Update /sdcard/dload/update.app failed
```

The entire process I did is based on [this tutorial](http://www.carbontesla.com/2015/06/honor-3c-u10-b320-emui-3-0-kitkat-international-firmware/). How to solve this?

Comment: Can you get into fastboot in the bootloader and attach the output of `fastboot oem get-bootinfo` and `fastboot getvar all` to the original question please?

Comment: I tried to get into fastboot but my PC does not recognize the phone.

Comment: You need to correct your driver issues so your computer can properly communicate with the phone before much of anything can be done. Without working fastboot and knowing the technical state of the device  there isn't much that can be done right now.

Comment: I am not familiar with your device model but owned Honor 6 earlier- for any upgrade please remove the external SD- for some unknown reason this was a common problem in Honor 6. Now that you can't access the device, change the external SD and copy the *dload* file on that and try See if that helps